# Hardware Acceleration

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today I noticed that vsc consumes almost 400 mb of my memory. Because of this thing sometimes it lags or causes other apps to lag. I have tried doing disable hardware acceleration in the argv.json but it doesn't help. Is there any other way to do so ? I have also tried excluding search indexing.

Comment: Do you have any additional extensions installed? Have you tried disabling them?

Comment: Unless the computer has insufficient RAM, it would be CPU usage which could cause laginess in other programs, and so hardware acceleration should reduce the problem. How much RAM does the computer have, and which other programs are affected?

Comment: I have 6gb of ram and I only have discord presence extension installed.